# A question on exercise 10.6(b) in Munkres - Analysis on Manifolds

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-sum, partitions-for-integration

Let $$I=I_1\times\cdots\times I_n=[a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times[a_n,b_n]$$ be a $n-$rectangle. Let $f:\ I\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ be bounded and $|f|\leq M$ on $I$.

Let $P=P_1\times\cdots\times P_n$ be a partition of $I$ where each $P_i$ is a partition of the interval $I_i$, which can be written as
$$P_i=\big\{a_i=p_{i0},\,p_{i1},\cdots,p_{i{m_i}}=b_i \big\}.$$
Suppose $P''$ be a partition obtained by adjoining a single point $q $ to one of $P_i$, which means
$$P''= P_1\times\cdots\times\big(P_i\cup\{q\}\big)\times\cdots\times P_n. $$
I want to show that
$$0\leq L(f,P'')-L(f,P)\leq 2M\|P\|\big(\text{width }I\big)^{n-1}. $$
where $\|P\|$ is the mesh of partition $P$, which is the maximum length of edge of subrectangles correspond to $P$.

My attempt :

First, we observe that since $P''$ is a refinement of $P$, so each subrectangle $S$ corresponds to $P''$ must be contained in some subrectangle $R$ corresponds to $P$. Thus, we have
\begin{align}
L(f,P'')=\sum_{S\in H(P'')}\inf_Sf|S|=\sum_{R\in H(P)}\sum_{\substack{S\in H(P'')\\ S\subseteq R}}\inf_Sf|S|
\end{align}
This implies
\begin{align}
L(f,P'')-L(f,P)&=\sum_{R\in H(P)}\sum_{\substack{S\in H(P'')\\ S\subseteq R}}\inf_Sf|S|-\sum_{R\in H(P)}\inf_Rf|R|
\\ &=\sum_{R\in H(P)}\left(\sum_{\substack{S\in H(P'')\\ S\subseteq R}}\inf_Sf|S|-\inf_Rf|R| \right)
\\ &=\sum_{R\in H(P)}\left(\sum_{\substack{S\in H(P'')\\ S=R}}\inf_Sf|S|-\inf_Rf|R| \right)+\sum_{R\in H(P)}\left(\sum_{\substack{S\in H(P'')\\ S\subset R,\ S\ne R}}\inf_Sf|S|-\inf_Rf|R| \right)
\\ &=\sum_{R\in H(P)}\left(\sum_{\substack{S\in H(P'')\\ S\subset R,\ S\ne R}}\inf_Sf|S|-\inf_Rf|R| \right)
\end{align}
since those terms in the sum involving $S=R$ will cancel.

Now, since $P''$ is obtained by adjoining a point $q$ in some $P_i$, so without loss of generality, we can assume that $q$ is added to $P_1$. Thus, if $q$ is added to some subinterval $R_1$ of $I_1$ and the subrectangle $R$ is of the form
\begin{align}
R&=R_1\times R_2\times\cdots\times R_n 
\\ &=\big[p_{1j_1},p_{1(j_1+1)}\big]\times\big[p_{2j_2},p_{2(j_2+1)}\big]\times\cdots\times\big[p_{nj_n},p_{n(j_n+1)}\big]
\end{align}
and notice that $R_1$ is devided into at most 2 new intervals, so if $S\subsetneq R$, it will be of the form
$$S=S_1\times R_2\times\cdots\times R_n\ \text{ where }\ S_1=\big[p_{1j_1},q\big]\ \text{ or }\ \big[q,p_{1(j_1+1)}\big] $$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
L(f,P'')-L(f,P)&=\sum_{R\in H(P)}\left[\left(\sum_{\substack{S\in H(P'')\\ S\subsetneq R}}\inf_Sf|S_1|-\inf_Rf|R_1|\right)|R_2|\cdots|R_n|\right]
\end{align}
Now, we consider this term
\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{S\in H(P'')\\ S\subsetneq R}}\inf_Sf|S_1|-\inf_Rf|R_1| &=\inf_{\big[p_{1j_1},q\big]}f\,\big(q-p_{1j_1} \big)+    \inf_{\big[q,p_{1(j_1+1)} \big]}f\,\big(p_{1(j_1+1)}-q \big)-\inf_Rf\,|R_1|
\\ &\leq M\big(q-p_{1j_1} \big)+M\big(p_{1(j_1+1)}-q \big)+M|R_1|
\\ &=M|R_1|+M|R_1|=2M|R_1|
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
L(f,P'')-L(f,P)&\leq 2M|R_1||R_2|\cdots|R_n|\leq 2M\|P\|\big(\text{width }I \big)^{n-1}.
\end{align}

Is my proof correct ? And if so, how can I show that if $P''$ is obtained by adjoining at most $N$ points to $P''$, then
$$L(f,P'')-L(f,P)\leq 2MN\|P\|\big(\text{width }I \big)^{n-1}\ ? $$
Could anyone give me some hints ? Thank you so much.